# Python logging extra info

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

If I have this python code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='allow.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s')
logging.debug(2+3)
```

but when I run it, I get a result like this which doesn't even have 5 from the 3+2:

```
2018-10-20 10:06:45,177
```

How can I make my result more like this:

```
2018-10-20 10:06:45 : 5
```

or even better:

```
Date: 2018-10-20, Time: 10:06:45 Answer: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `%(message)s` in the format string in order for the log message to be logged:

```
logging.basicConfig(..., format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s')
```

You can include the strings "Date" and "Time" in the timestamp by configuring the `datefmt` argument:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    ... ,
    datefmt='Date: %Y-%m-%d, Time: %H:%M:%S',
    format='%(asctime)s Answer: %(message)s',
)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can delete the millisecond data?

Answer (score 1):

- You forgot %(message)s
- You can use datefmt optional parameter

  ```
  import logging
  logging.basicConfig(filename='allow.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s', datefmt="Date: %Y-%m-%d Time: %H:%M:%S")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is inside the `format` argument. Your log-message formatter prints only time in the asc-format. You should add `message` argument.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='allow.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s')
logging.debug(2+3)
```

Will result in: `2018-10-20 20:27:44,082 : 5`

To use "best-case", you should add the date-formatter.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='allow.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s Answer: %(message)s', datefmt="Date: %Y-%m-%d, Time: %H:%M:%S")
```

Will result in:
`Date: 2018-10-20, Time: 20:29:29 Answer: 5`